# Import json file in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

i am getting the error after importing the file 
"the file specified not found by system"
Where should i [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AE8I2.png)save my json file

Comment: Still it is not importing . I have saved the file in bin folder .from there i am importing the json file but no result

Answer (score 0):

you haven't started the mongoDb server mate.

type **mongo** and hit enter. after that run your command.

**NOTE :**
resttt.json file that you are trying to import, should be in the same folder